# Can not generate XML documentation help file with Sandcastle (SHFB)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, documentation, sandcastle

I have a C++ MFC project with only classes and no namespace.I want to create a Help file from XML documentation. I was trying to do that using Sandcastle help file builder and the visual studio generated document XML file. But each time I try to build the help file it shows :

```
SHFB: Error BE0033: No APIs found to document.  See error topic in help file for details.
```

Is it not possible for Sandcastle to create documentation for this kind of project (i.e no namespace used).I am a beginner in this part so not sure if I am going in right direction at all or not. Any kind of guide is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: :try to edit the DocumentPrivateFields and DocumentPrivates to True instead of False

Answer (score 1):

If the classes are not public you'll have to enable *DocumentPrivates* and *DocumentInternals* in the project properties. This can be changed within the 'Visibility' section.

This FAQ [answer](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/1aea789d-b226-4b39-b534-4c97c256fac8.htm#NoAPIs) may be helpful.